# Test php mail function in localhost on Mac using XAMPP

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to test php mail function in localhost using this [method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081217161612647):

As it says on the site there are 3 steps to set up:

1. Modify `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
2. Create files `/etc/postfix/smtp_sasl_passwords` and `/etc/postfix/smtp_tls_sites`
3. Run the following commands:

   `$ cd /etc/postfix`
   `$ chmod go-rx smtp_sasl_passwords`
   `$ postmap smtp_sasl_passwords`
   `$ postmap smtp_tls_sites`

When I run `$ postmap smtp_sasl_passwords`, terminal returned `postmap: fatal: open database smtp_sasl_passwords.db: Permission denied`. I also tried to add `sudo` command: `sudo postmap smtp_sasl_passwords` (as I learnt from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRJSQjXGjOA) [7:30]), but it also returned the same error. I'm not sure where I went wrong?

P.S. I did some searching on Stack Overflow but solutions I found did not seem to suit me.

Comment: Who voted -1 for the post? May I be advised what I did wrong?

Comment: if its an email u want to send via  PHP on a xampp server, i suggest you use  the `mail()` function (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp); All u would need is internet access and ur mail would be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

You have to create 2 sets of files

```
smtp_sasl_passwords
smtp_sasl_passwords.db
smtp_tls_sites
smtp_tls_sites.db
```

Since `postmap smtp_sasl_passwords` detects the `db` extension.

Comment: Hi Alvin, I have the same issue. I still get the same error even after creating those new files. Any ideas?